# unknown LINE 1: select "id" from"notifications" where"data"->>'id' = $1 You might need to add explicit type casts(SQL: select"id"from"notifications"

Tags: heroku-postgres, laravel-9

i make project with laravel and i upload it on the heroku i used notifications so data column in notification table stored like {"id":36,"total":"300","tableNum":"6"} these data for order

i used this code to make notification unread

```
public function show($id)  //$id refers to order id in this example id = 36
{
  $getId = DB::table('notifications')->where("data->id", $id)->pluck('id');
  DB::table('notifications')->where('id', $getId)->update(['read_at' => now()]);
  return redirect()->route('current');
}
```

this code runs without any errors, but in heroku make an error "cast" what can i do ?

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
LINE 1: select "id" from "notifications" where "data"->>'id' = $1
^
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select "id" from "notifications" where "data"->>'id' = 1)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your current example.
->where("data->id", $id)

It should either be "id" or $data->id, but it's hard to assume based from the code you just posted. However,  your answer could be simplified by just using this. Don't need to pluck id and use it again for another query

```
public function show($id)  //$id refers to order id in this example id = 36
{
  DB::table('notifications')->where('id', $id)->update(['read_at' => now()]);
  return redirect()->route('current');
}
```